# How to pull current day's logs in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I am new to VBScript and I need some help with a script. I need to pull only 3 files each day in a VBScript. Right now my script is pulling everything from C:\Windows\Logs\WindowsServerBackup but I need to limit the pull to only the current days (Backup-05-05-2017_11-06-13.log, Backup_Operations-05-05-2017_17-52-06.log and Backup_Error-05-05-2017_17-56-06.log). I don't know how to create a parameter for the current date.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Option Explicit

Const c_RoboLogDirectory = "D:\RoboLogs"
Const c_LogFileDirectory = "C:\Windows\Logs\WindowsServerBackup"

Dim fldLogFiles
Dim flsLogFiles
Dim fldRoboLogs
Dim flsRoboLogs
Dim objEmail
Dim objFSO
Dim strFile
Dim strFile1

objEmail.From = c_Sender
objEmail.To = c_Receiver
objEmail.Subject = c_Subject

' get all the files within the folder and attach them to the email
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set fldLogFiles = objFSO.GetFolder(c_LogFileDirectory)
Set flsLogFiles = fldLogFiles.Files

Set fldRoboLogs = objFSO.GetFolder(c_RoboLogDirectory)
Set flsRoboLogs = fldRoboLogs.Files

For Each strFile In flsLogFiles
    objEmail.AddAttachment strFile
Next

For Each strFile1 In flsRoboLogs
    objEmail.AddAttachment strFile1
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a string from today's date:

```
Function Pad(num)
    Pad = Right("00" & num, 2)
End Function

today   = Date
datestr = Pad(Month(today)) & "-" & Pad(Day(today)) & "-" & Year(today)
```

and only attach files when the filename contains that string:

```
If InStr(strFile.Name, datestr) > 0 Then
    objEmail.AddAttachment strFile
End If
```